# how to post on the user's twitter wall via my app?

Tags: php, post, twitter

I have a code, where people can post messages on the app's wall via my app

```
         $consumerKey = '';
    $consumerSecret = '';
    $accessToken = '';
    $accessTokenSecret = '';

    $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

    $tweetMessage = $_POST['message'];

   if(strlen($tweetMessage)<=140)
   {
       $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetMessage));

       $day = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (message,data,social) VALUES ('".$_POST['message']."','".$day."','tw')");
   }
```

how can I make the script to post messages from users on their own walls via my app ?

is it possible?

thank you!

Comment: You can't make users post statuses to Twitter without their authorization, which you don't appear to have here.

Comment: (As a side note: Twitter has timelines, not "walls". Being familiar with the service and its terminology will help you form your question better, and will also explain why some things are the way they are.)

Comment: It's all here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

Comment: @duskwuff thank you for your answer and note. couldn't you send me a link where there is an authorization with the service I'd like to have? thank you )

Comment: @popnoodles, there is nothing about the question there...couldn't you give me, maybe, another link?

Comment: Sure, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=twitter+API+post+tweet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, now that I think of it, what you probably want here is not a Twitter application at all. Since you want your visitors to post messages themselves, the correct way to do this is by using [Twitter Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents).